# NextJs Middleware not reading cookie until page refresh?

Tags: next.js, cookies, middleware, vercel

I have a NextJs site where I use middleware to ensure a user "has" a session cookie to allow them into certain pages. It works fine in localhost, but when I upload it to Vercel I cannot access the protected routes even though I'm logged in. That is until I refresh the page and then it works??

Usually I can track down these bugs, but I'm at a loss on this one... At first I thought it was a CORS issue, but it works after refresh... Then for some reason I considered if it was a https issue, but I don't think so...

Any ideas on how I can get middleware to see the cookie immediately?